# How to scroll divs in opposite direction on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs, that contain images aligned vertically. I want the the first div to scroll down when the user scrolls down, simultaneously the other div should scroll up (note: there aren't scrollbars on the divs, only on the body).

[image]

here's what I have tried, only the div scrolling upwards works, the downwards scroll is stuck.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

  const boundingRect = parallaxSection.getBoundingClientRect()
  const top = boundingRect.top

  // const topPercent = (top / parallaxSection.clientHeight ) * 100 
  // const bottomPercent = (boundingRect.bottom / parallaxSection.clientHeight ) * 100 

  const percentage = (window.scrollY / parallaxSection.clientHeight) * 100;

  column1.style.transform = `translateY(${percentage}%)`

  // column1.style.top = `${percentage * 1.5}%`
  // column1.style.bottom = `${100 - percentage}%`
  column2.style.transform = `translateY(-${window.scrollY}px)`

})
```

```html
<div class="tw-h-[200vh] tw-flex tw-relative tw-overflow-clip tw-snap-end tw-snap-y" id="parallax-img-section">

  <div class="tw-absolute tw-w-full tw-h-[200vh]">

    <div class="tw-sticky tw-top-0 tw-left-0 ">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/33703/relay-race-competition-stadium-sport.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" srcset="" class="tw-w-full tw-h-full
                                                    tw-object-cover">
    </div>
    <div class="tw-absolute tw-top-0 tw-left-0 tw-bg-[#030303da] tw-w-[100%] tw-h-[100%]">
      <!-- this is overlay -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tw-flex tw-w-[60%] tw-gap-[5%] tw-place-content-center">
    <div class="tw-h-fit tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-gap-4 tw-w-fit tw-bg-white tw-absolute 
                         tw-left-[10%] scrolling-cols" style="bottom: 100%;" id="col1">

      <div class="tw-h-[350px] tw-w-[250px] tw-rounded-lg tw-shadow-lg tw-flex tw-overflow-clip">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5641089/pexels-photo-5641089.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="" srcset="" class="tw-w-full tw-h-full">
      </div>
      ...
    </div>

    <div class="tw-h-full tw-w-fit tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-gap-4 tw-absolute 
                                    tw-top-[100%] tw-left-[30%] scrolling-cols" id="col2">

      <div class="tw-h-[350px] tw-w-[250px] tw-rounded-lg tw-shadow-lg tw-flex tw-overflow-clip">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/159515/football-american-football-runner-player-159515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600" alt="" srcset="" class="tw-w-full tw-h-full">
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how do I acheive the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

> I want the the first div to scroll down when the user scrolls down, simultaneously the other div should scroll up

You're definitely on the right track and you're mostly there, using

- `window.scroll`
- `transform: translateY()`

Here's an approach using those two properties.

When running the code snippet below, switch to *Full Page View* for a better effect.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const rect1 = document.querySelector('.rect1');
const rect2 = document.querySelector('.rect2');

const moveDivs = () => {
  
  const scrollbarHeight = (window.innerHeight / (document.body.scrollHeight / window.innerHeight));
  const percentageScrolled = (window.scrollY / document.body.scrollHeight * 100).toFixed(2);
  
  let distanceToMove = ((window.innerHeight / 100) * percentageScrolled);
  distanceToMove += ((scrollbarHeight / 100) * percentageScrolled);
  distanceToMove = distanceToMove.toFixed(2);
  
  rect1.style.setProperty('transform', `translateY(${distanceToMove}px)`);
  rect2.style.setProperty('transform', `translateY(-${distanceToMove}px)`);
}


window.addEventListener('scroll', moveDivs);
```

```css
body {
  height: 400vh;
}

.rect {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
}

.rect1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 36vw;
  background-color: red;
}

.rect2 {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 36vw;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect rect1"></div>
<div class="rect rect2"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I tried to implement your code, but I am still having the same problem. The column1 is jittering when scrolling see this [video](https://imgur.com/a/iMMET95).